# Android periodic task every 5 minutes

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-workmanager, android-handler

I need to download some data from my webservice every 5 minutes (user is allowed to change this interval time, but the minimum is every 5 min), and because Android's `WorkManager` is aimed to work with intervals greater than 15 minutes, I thought in using `RxJava Observable.interval` or even `Handler` with its `postDelayed` methods.

The work should be done while the app is in foreground or in background, but I want it to stop when the app is closed.

Is it correct my approach or do you advise me to use any other library? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to download it from background(when application is closed) then there is no solution. You need root access to run background jobs with time period < 15 minutes

Comment: sorry, I want it to run in a second thread (not ui main thread) but not when app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timer and a TimerTask (where your code is to download the data) which is run by the Timer every 5min.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //download data
    }
}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 300 * 1000);
```

Comment: I've read TimerTask is not reliable and should not be used.

Comment: Sorry I corrected the code.
I use it often and it works very well

Comment: If your app goes to the background and there's no foreground service running, the Timer is not guaranteed to be executed.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini sorry, I meant a second thread (not main thread), but I want it to run even whenever the app is in foreground or in background, but I want it to stop when the app is closed.

Comment: Yes, if there is no foreground service it is not guaranteed that the task will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling webservice which will drain user's battery, use firebase cloud messaging:

1. android app launched, it can get firebase token
2. android app sends this token to the webservice
3. when some event triggered webservice sends push notification using token to the google firebase
4. google play services wakes up your application with data.

If you can't use firebase - the only way is a foreground service with sticky notification in the status bar which is pretty annoying for user. Anyway even with foreground service you will not able to work if a device screen is off with such a short timeout.